# Why am I getting only the last element of the JSon array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to get the data from `MongoDB` database. I have already saved the data and this is how it looks like.

```
    [
    {
        "_id": "5d977c6771384613e9b305ea",
        "vendor": "2",
        "invoiceDate": "2019-10-04T00:00:00.000Z",
        "expectedDate": "2019-10-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "billingAddress": "Hi",
        "contactPerson": "Machan",
        "items": [
            {}, // what is this? I don't know how an empty element is created
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "qty": 0,
                "unitPrice": 10,
                "linePrice": 10
            },
            {
                "_id": 5,
                "qty": 12,
                "unitPrice": 10,
                "linePrice": 10
            }
        ],
        "totalPrice": 10,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

And I am getting this data from `axio` and keep them in `state` in `ReactJS` like this:

And this is my `state` attributes I am trying to store `items` array:

```
this.state = {
  items:[{}]
}
```

And this is how I am getting the data from `MongoDB` and store them in `state`

```
    componentDidMount() {

    let getPathName = window.location.pathname;
    let pathName = getPathName.slice(13);
    this.setState({
      invoiceIdFromUrl: pathName
    });

    //fill the fileds
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:4005/purchaseinvoices/" + this.props.match.params.id
      )
      .then(response => {
        var invoiceDate = new Date(
          response.data.invoiceDate
        ).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "2-digit",
          day: "2-digit"
        });

        var arr = [];
        arr = invoiceDate.toString().split("/");
        var invoiceDateNew = arr[2] + "-" + arr[0] + "-" + arr[1];

        var expectedDate = new Date(
          response.data.expectedDate
        ).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "2-digit",
          day: "2-digit"
        });

        var arr2 = [];
        arr2 = expectedDate.toString().split("/");
        var expectedDateNew = arr2[2] + "-" + arr2[0] + "-" + arr2[1];

        this.setState({
          invoiceID: response.data._id,
          vendorName: response.data.vendor,
          invoiceDate: invoiceDateNew,
          expectedDate: expectedDateNew,
          address: response.data.billingAddress,
          contactPerson: response.data.contactPerson,
          rows: [...this.state.rows, response.data.items]
        });
      });
   }
```

As you can see, there are two `items` in my database with `_id`s **2 and 5**

But everytime **I alert (this.state.rows.length)** I only got `2` where I am supposed to get `3`  (since initial state of `rows[{}]` is an empty array with length = 1  and **only first item with _id = 2** is being printed when I try to print the `rows` array.

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Is the response from the AJAX call giving the right data? Or is it only returning the first item? If the server is only returning the one element, then we need to know the server code to know what's wrong.

Comment: I think it is something wrong with the rows state. When I normally pass a data (something I wrote in JSON format) it only prints the first element

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka As a check what does `response.data` or `response.data.items` from `axios` gives you.

Comment: I fixed the problem using adding spreaded operator to `rows: [...this.state.rows, ...response.data.items]`